# Ways of referring to names

Tags: choix-de-mot

The standard method all French learners are taught is to use *s'appeller.* But is this the only way? What alternatives are there, how common are they, and when could they be used (if not always)? Are they more formal?

For instance:

> Il s'appelle Pascal.

vs.

> Il se nomme Pascal.

vs.

> Son nom est Pascal. (is this even allowed?)

Are there other ways? In English I can just say "This is Pascal" or "That's Pascal"....are *C'est Pascal / Il est Pascal* permissible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les trois sont tout à fait corrects, dans l'ordre :

> « Il s'appelle Pascal. » - le plus courant;
>   « Il se nomme Pascal. » - le plus recherché;
>   « Son nom est Pascal. » - le plus administratif.

---

All these three phrases are correct:

> « Il s'appelle Pascal. » - most usual;
>   « Il se nomme Pascal. » - most refined;
>   « Son nom est Pascal. » - most formal.

---

Cette réponse a été initialement écrit comme un commentaire par [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r).

Answer (score 2):

Marc's answer is correct.
To complete it :

> "Voilà Pascal"

also fits : when Pascal is close to you and you introduce him to new colleagues (for instance). Or when you are with other people and he is coming to the group.

"C'est Pascal" is not used in this context.

"Il est Pascal" is not grammatically correct.

Comment: (You should expand on what context it *is* used in.)

Comment: *C'est Pascal* would be used to designate *Pascal* among other people for example.